# Regex: How to delete a a html tag from another html tag paragraph

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this paragraph:

`<p class="dobe">Intră pe site-ul magazinului comandă un xerox 3D (ceea ce puteţi face şi voi intrând pe site-ul </a>  sau la numărul de telefon. Dupa ce primi xerox-ul se multiplică de atâtea ori câte oraşe există pe lume. Îşi instrui copiile să ştie unde şi cum să aşeze ouăle.</p>`

I want only to delete that `</a>` followed by a space

My regex is not good, because is deleted the entire line, after `</a>` not just `</a>`

FIND: `</a>.+\w+`

REPLACE BY: `LEAVE EMPTY`

I also try this regex, but it delete my word `sau` next to it:

FIND: `</a>([\s\S]*?)\w+`

REPLACE BY: `LEAVE EMPTY`

Comment: What  happened if it is followed by a space like the example you have given?

Comment: What should be the result for `<p>Blah blah</a>. Blah</p>` ?

Comment: the result should be delete only tag `</a>`, replace it with empty

Comment: OK, but this is not a letter after `</a>`.

Comment: yes, sorry. Without any letter after `</a>`  just empty space.

Comment: @JustMe You wrote "I want only to delete that </a> followed by a letter", but it seems that you want something else. Should it be followed by letter or not?

Comment: @JustMe you might want to edit your post and correct the misleading information instead of just adding a clarification as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like this is working.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `</a>(?=\W*\w)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

It matches `</a>` followed by 0 or more non word character then a word character.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the folowing:

- Find what: `</a>(?=[a-z])`
- Replace by: leave empty
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Match case: disable

Comment: doesn't work. See this print screen:  https://snipboard.io/n765Wy.jpg

I believe you mean `</a>.+?(?=[a-z])`  Please test this and edit your answer @Reddy